# Adding a new directory to PATH vs. a symlink for directory already in PATH

Tags: bash, shell, symlink, path

In setting it up so I could execute Sublime Text from bash, I discovered two methods of doing this via different tutorials:

**Method 1) Create a symlink from `/usr/local/bin/subl` to Sublime's bin dir:**

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl`

This took advantage that `/usr/local/bin` is already in my PATH variable.

...or...

**Method 2) Update your PATH to include the path to Sublime's bin folder:**

`export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/":$PATH`

**Both work, but I'm wondering if one method is better than the other, or are they equally fine?**

The only advantage I can potentially see is for Method 1 if is if it's beneficial to have less dirs in your PATH directory (speed/performance in looking for the executable?).

Comment: Your conclusion is absolutely correct. - Mind also, that you would get horrendous (unmaintainable) PATH definitions if every application would add its own path to PATH. - Note, though; if the program shall  only be accessible for your account (not for all users), better put in your local `$HOME/bin` and add that to your PATH in your own shell profile.

Comment: When using method 2, it might be safer to use `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/"` so the sbt stuffs don't come before original system binaries. For OS X, you may also add one file named, say, `80-sbt` in `/etc/paths.d` containing the line `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/`.

Comment: @Arthur2e5: Why it's `80-sbt` not `79-sbt`?

Comment: @Niing The two digit numbers that go before filenames help sort out the sequence of inclusion naturally by a glob like `*`. There isn't really a reason to pick 80 over 79; I just went for a number that is not very early so as not to interfere with other stuff.

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for way **to run/execute program/script as a command directly from terminal**, then I think putting scripts or links to `/usr/local/bin` is good choice!

Also the advantage is that it is already in path. Visit [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/465109) related post.

But if a program directory provides several executables, then I think exporting path of that directory may useful/better than creating several symlinks individually.

Comment: So I can't create a symlink of `...some_app/bin` that would do the same as `export PATH=...`?

Answer (score 6):

Adding a symlink to a directory already in your `PATH`  is often preferable.

If you want the software to be visible system-wide (by other users), add a symlink to `/usr/local/bin`. If you want the software to be visible only by you, add once `$HOME/bin/` to your `PATH`  (some distributions are configuring the `bash`  shell to add that directory automagically if it exists) and add symlinks from it.

You should avoid having a very long `PATH` (so avoid adding a directory in it for every newly installed applications), both for performance (but some shells are caching `PATH`  lookup, so that might not matter that much) and for maintainability purposes (you'll have a mess if your `PATH`  contain dozens of directories); this is also true for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (so better add symlinks from `$HOME/lib/` ...).

You might also **consider using [GNU stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/)** which partly automate the process (I tried to use it a few years ago, but felt that it is not worth the burden).

At last, many software that you compile from source code can be configured to be installed somewhere else than under `/usr/local/`  and its `/usr/local/bin/`  directory. For free software configured with [GNU autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) facilities (i.e. having a `configure` script generated from `configure.ac`....), you may want to pass `--prefix=$HOME/pub/ --exec-prefix=$HOME/bin/` and some other options (e.g. `--program-suffix=-mine`, ...) at build time.

A **third method** of doing would be to ***wrap* your executable in some shell script** which `export`-s an augmented `PATH`  e.g. using `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/something/bin` .... (this is necessary if the executable is forking more internal processes executed thru `execvp`); BTW most firefox installations are doing that (so `firefox` or `mozilla`  would be a shell script ending with `exec mozilla.bin` ....), or in a script which end by `exec`-ing the full path. so you might simply add a small shell script as `$HOME/bin/sublimetext` (assuming `$HOME/bin/`  is *already* in your `PATH`) containing

```
#!/bin/sh
# file $HOME/bin/sublimetext
# if needed add export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin 
exec /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl "$@"
```

and you could even name that script `$HOME/bin/subl`  if you want to; don't forget to make your script executable with `chmod u+rx $HOME/bin/subl`

Comment: So I can't create a symlink of `...some_app/bin` that would do the same as `export PATH=...`?